# Iterable unpacking and slice assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
L = [0, 1, 2]
L[::2], *rest = "abcdef"
print(L, rest)
```

Expected output:

```
['a', 1, 'b'] ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Actual output:

```
ValueError: attempt to assign sequence of size 1 to extended slice of size 2
```

Is using unpacking assignment in combination with extended slice assignment not possible for some reason? Why? I don't see anything obvious in [PEP 3132 -- Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) or in the Python datamodel suggesting this shouldn't be valid.

Comment: This is a problem without PEP 3132 too, e.g. `a, L[::2] = "abc"` doesn't work (`a, L[::2] = [1, [2, 3]]` works, but is much less interesting). This seems like a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a bug. Unpacking is always done by mapping each item in the right-hand iterable to the corresponding comma-separated left-hand expression when there are more than one left-hand expressions. The `L[::2]` expression in your example is just one of the two left-hand expressions, and it therefore receives just one item from unpacking the right-hand iterable while the starred left-hand expression receives the rest.

As the rationale in PEP-3132 points out:

> Many algorithms require splitting a sequence in a "first, rest" pair.
>   With the new syntax,
>
> ```
> first, rest = seq[0], seq[1:]
> ```
>
> is replaced by the cleaner and probably more efficient:
>
> ```
> first, *rest = seq
> ```

your:

```
L[::2], *rest = "abcdef"
```

is therefore equivalent to:

```
L[::2], rest = "a", "bcdef"
```

which would thus result in the said error of `ValueError: attempt to assign sequence of size 1 to extended slice of size 2` since `"a"` cannot be further unpacked for a slice of 2.

If Python were to add your interpretation of unpacking into the syntax, it can make, for example, the statement of:

```
L[::2], *rest = "ab", "c", "d"
```

ambiguous--should `L` become `["a", 1, "b"]` and `rest` become `["c", "d"]`, or should `L` become `["ab", 1, "c"]`, and `rest` become `["d"]`? Always allotting one item in the iterable per LHS expression makes the interpretation much clearer and less prone to runtime errors.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, it also explains why `L = [1,2,3,4]; L[1:3], *r = "abcd"` works the way it does. It's still surprising.

Comment: I'm aware of how/why it *does* raise, but my question was more about whether this can possibly be implemented to be a bit more flexible. When an assignment on the LHS hooks into `__getitem__` and wants to consume more than one element, then Python should be able to figure the "one obvious way to do it" here, shouldn't it?

Comment: @wim Yes, but to me your interpretation isn't necessarily the obvious way, since IMHO your proposal would make `L[::2], *rest = (1, 2), 3, 4` ambiguous--should `L` become `[1, 1, 2]` and `rest` become `[3, 4]`, or should `L` become `[(1, 2), 1, 3]`, and `rest` become `[4]`? Always allotting one item in the iterable per LHS expression makes the interpretation much clearer and less prone to runtime errors.

Comment: @blhsing  Hmm, yes, that was the kind of potential ambiguity I was grasping for - perhaps you could edit this details into your answer?  (FWIW I think the `[(1, 2), 1, 3]` and `[4]` result would be clearly the more sensible one here)

Comment: i.e. to get the the first result `[1, 1, 2]` and `[3, 4]`, it would require an assignment such as  `(L[::2],), *rest = (1, 2), 3, 4`

Comment: @wim I've updated my answer with a better example that demonstrates the potential ambiguity your proposal would create.